# A byte is ignored by the computer when casting a char[] to a struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, casting, char

I'm writing a client-server program where the client-side is written in C++ and the server-side is in Python.

A stream of bytes is sent from the server-side and received to a `char[]` buffer and then converted with `reinterpret_cast` to an appropriate struct.

```
char response_buffer[7];
recv(sock, response_buffer, 7, 0);
s_response* response = reinterpret_cast<s_response*>(response_buffer);
cout << response -> code << endl;
```

where the struct is defined this way:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char version;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int payload_size;
} s_response;
```

But instead of `version` (*1 byte*) getting the value in `response_buffer[0]`, and `code` getting `response_buffer[1]` and `response_buffer[2]` (*two bytes*), `code` ends up getting the value in `response_buffer[2]` and `response_buffer[3]`, and `payload_size` getting `response_buffer[4]` to `response_buffer[6]`, and thus, the value `response_buffer[1]` is not inserted into any of the struct's attributes and the result is a whole mess.

At first, I thought that it's due to endianness, but when I send the values **2**, **2001**, and **13821**, for example, from the server-side, the following values are in `response_buffer`:

```
0. 00000010
1. 11101001
2. 00000011
3. 11111101
4. 00110101
5. 00000000
6. 00000000
```

This **is** what I expect to get and in the right order. But when I print out `response->code` I get the value `64771` which is `11111101 00000011` (2 and 3 in the above list) instead of `2001` which is `00000011 11101001` (1 and 2 in the list). Meaning, when I'm casting the `char*` to the `s_response*`, the byte in position 1 in the `response_buffer` is just ignored, and the values from there-on are one-byte shifted from the correct order.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Also, if you attempt to see what `sizeof` of the structure is, you might be surprised, and figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: `char response_buffer[7];` may not be large enough to hold an object of type `s_response` (due to struct padding) - you should be using `char response_buffer[sizeof(s_response)];` instead

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<s_response*>(response_buffer)` looks like UB.

Comment: If you're using TCP, you need to check how much you received, and only parse the data when you get enough to be able to.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the comments, it was struct padding that made the problem.
It can be solved by adding `#pragma`s as shown below

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct {
    unsigned char version;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int payload_size;
} s_response;
#pragma pack(pop)
```